# IIS UnAuthorize xml response

Tags: c#, iis, smoothing, unauthorized

When I call serever like this:

```
       var client = new RestClient();
       client.Authenticator =  new NtlmAuthenticator();

       var request = new RestRequest(uri); 
       request.Method = Method.POST;
       request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;

       request.AddParameter("application/atom+xml", doc /*some xml document*/, ParameterType.RequestBody);
       IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

       Debug.WriteLine(response.Content); 

       if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
          // always 401
        }
```

I get next server responce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SmoothStreaming xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/iis/media/2011/03/streaming/management">
    <Error>
         <ErrorCode>0x80880022</ErrorCode>
         <ErrorMessage>All requests to the management APIs must be authenticated. Please install and enable an appropriate IIS authentication module for this website.</ErrorMessage>
    </Error>
</SmoothStreaming>
```

What and where should I change (install)?

Comment: I am not sily.If there were specifyed what module I need to install I will not ask then.I enabled all existing that iis have.

Comment: why do you think your error has anything to do with IIS modules and not the actual authentication against the API?  If you're unclear about how to authenticate against a web service that's not yours, you should ask the creator for what type of authentication they're using and possible credentials.

Comment: thanks,I am not thinking about it.